# Matching a list of ip addresses with another file with ip addresses

Tags: bash

I was given the task to retrieve a long list of ip addresses from another file with ip addresses. I created this bash script but it does not work very well. After executing the script I check the file called "found" there is nothing, and when I check the file called "notfound" there are about 60 ip addresses. In both files there has to be a total of 1500 ip addresses. There are two files; 1. list of ip addresses to retrieve(findtheseips.txt), 2. list of ip addresses to retrieve from(listips.txt). Can anybody please help me to make it work. Thank you very much. I run the script this way: **./script findtheseips.txt**

```
 #!/bin/bash

 declare -a ARRAY
 exec 10<&0
 exec < $1
 let count=0

 while read LINE; do
 ARRAY[$count]=$LINE
 if egrep "$LINE" listips.txt; then
    echo "$LINE" >> found
   else
    echo "$LINE" >> notfound
 fi
done
```

Comment: You're missing a `$` in the `egrep` line. Is that just a copying error?

Comment: Yes Barmar it is a copying error. Thank you.

Comment: No really Barmar. That script I had to type so many ip addresses manually, but I thought that there has to be a way to just read the list of ip addresses into the bash and let the script do the job. I actually end up with a different script. It works good but I had to type in manually every ip addresses and that is a long time.

Comment: Doesn't my answer using `comm` work?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about. Neither of the answers in that question require you to type anything manually. They both get the IPs from files.

Comment: Yes, actually I was looking into that option right now. You advised to sort the two files and for that end I need to use the command ed to edit the file and sort the ip addresses. Thank you

Comment: Why can't you use the `sort` command?

Comment: Because I am not sure how to use it, I think I am more familiar with the command ed. I am reading a book to get a several commands for this script.

Comment: I've updated my answer there to show how to use the sort command. It's trivial, every Unix scripter should know it.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to try to use `exec` or to create an array.

You could `read` from the script's first argument `$1`.

There shouldn't be a need to use `egrep` unless you're trying to do extended regular expression matching.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read LINE; do
    if grep "$LINE" listips.txt; then
        echo "$LINE" >> found
    else
        echo "$LINE" >> notfound
    fi
done < $1
```

Here is an all BASH solution.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read l1; do
    n=0
    while read l2; do
        if [[ $l1 == $l2 ]]; then
            echo "$l1" >> found
            ((n++))
        fi
    done < ips2
    if [ $n -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "$l1" >> notfound
    fi
done < $1
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will try it. Probably I am making it more complicated than what it is. Thank you

Comment: This can have false positives. It will match substrings, and `.` in IPs will match anything. Use `grep -x -F` rather than `egrep`.

Comment: I used `egrep` simply because it was what the OP used.  Either way, it will not produce false positives.  I tested it and updated the script to suggest using only `grep`.

Comment: Thank you very much guys. Any comment helps a lot. I am trying different things and I am learning so much from you guys. Thank you, thank you.

Comment: For future people looking for the same answer. This script did not work for me. It creates only the file notfound but there is no found file, which makes this script unpredictable. Thank you any ways.

Comment: It creates the `found` file when I run the script.  Not sure why it didn't work for you.

Comment: My bad, it creates the file. Thank you.

Comment: I counted the lines in every file and it adds up to the total number of ip addresses to find. I would like to double check it manually but that would be pointless so I will check a few ip addresses randomly. Thank you John it works.

Comment: Hello John, yes there are false positives, like a lot of them. Thank you any ways.

Comment: Did you remove the `found` and `notfound` files before testing the script again?  If you didn't, you would get duplicate results appended to the file every time you ran the script.